# SharePoint REST and Power Apps

Tags: rest, powerapp

How I can use SharePoint REST API in Power Apps using Custom Connectors?

I am following [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/register-custom-api) to create postman collection which is successful, but I am not sure how to integrate this in Power Apps.

Anyone tried to do this?

Take an example of calling `https://sitename/_api/web/sitegroups`, which will give you the list of site groups.

Answer (score 1):

To use SharePoint list you can use in-build connector but ***at this point*** there are no in-build functions or connector available to consume SharePoint native rest endpoints expect [Office365Users](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/connections/connection-office365-users) function

---

However, PowerApps and MSFlow can only speak via [OpenAPI aka Swagger](http://swagger.io/) endpoint. you need to comply those rules to be able to use in your app.

AzureFunction is by far best way to use for these scenarios(Decision is up to you).

> **Reference:** Below articles has detailed step-by-step procedure to achieve this.
>
> - [Create SwaggerAPI endpoint for AzureFunctions](http://ratsubsharewall.blogspot.com/2017/12/create-swagger-api-endpoint-for-azure.html)
> - [Custom connectors for PowerApps and MSFlow from AzureFunctions](http://ratsubsharewall.blogspot.com/2018/01/create-and-configure-custom-connectors-for-powerapps-and-msflow-using-azurefunctions.html)

Comment: But creating swagger file becoming complex. My Azure subscription not allowing me to create Azure functions

Comment: Like I mention AzureFunction is the easy way to create/expose OpenApi based functionalities.. but you can still use your own WebAPI as long as it is accessible as a REST API... And it is easy to learn also its matter of understanding.. recommend you to go through the links provided in the answer and start with simple `GET` operation. you can try your API endpoint in this swagger editor http://editor2.swagger.io/